# How to find period of a sum of periodic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, trigonometry, signal-processing, periodic-functions

I got this function:

$$
x[n]=\sin(2*\pi*4/3*n) + \cos(2*\pi*5/2*n)
$$

It is easy to see that period of the `sin` is `3/4` and the period of the `cos` is `2/5`.

Now, what do I have to do to get the period of the whole function?

I know that the period is `6`. Solved in [this wolfram alpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=period+y%3Dsin%282*pi*n*4%2F3%29%2Bcos%282*pi*n*5%2F2%29).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two periodic functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have periods $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ respectively. The sum $f(x)+g(x)$ has period $lcm(T_{1},T_{2})$.

In this case, the lowest common multiple (that is an integer) of $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{5}$ is 6.

Comment: Great! But `6` wouldn't be the lowest common multiple of the two numerators only? $lcm(3,2)$ ?

Comment: No we are talking about $\frac{3p}{4}$ and $\frac{2q}{5}$  where $p$ and $q$ are integers such that both fractions are the same integer. In this case $p=8$ and $q=15$ are the lowest such integers $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Awesome! I would upvote your comment if I could. Thanks!

Comment: You could upvote the answer if you wanted. ;-). Just kidding (maybe I'm not). You're welcome btw.

Comment: I only have 8 of reputation ✌️. I'm a newbie here in this community, but I will upvote this answer when I get more of 15.. Thanks btw.